# Process Images and resize them on a Ktor server

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I am trying to receive an image using a Ktor server, and process it, all the Android libraries aren't working as they use things like BitmapFactory, java.awt.* , Buffered images and etc.
Does Ktor have any set of tools to process images? 
What I am trying to achieve is to receive an image and resize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ktor doesn't have anything specific to process the images. Because it doesn't have to.

`BufferedImage` is not an Android library. It's part of `java.awt`, and you can use it in Ktor code. Same for `javax.imageio.ImageIO`. The only part you can't use is `BitmapFactory`, since it is part of Android SDK.

As of the part how to get the initial upload (since you're using Ktor, that's what you want, probably), you can look here: https://ktor.io/servers/uploads.html

This should work on Kotlin JVM:

```
import javax.imageio.*
import java.io.*

fun main() {
    val image = ImageIO.read(File(""))
}
```

Comment: Trying to find any ports to the following libs with no luck so far(

Comment: `javax` is part of standard Java distribution. You shouldn't need to find ports of it.

Comment: Couldn't use it on a clean Ktor install, not surprising its only Kotlin

Comment: Is it Kotlin Native? There's no such thing as "only Kotlin", since Kotlin for JVM uses Java classes. You can see that it works: https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjIxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJmb2xkZWRCdXR0b24iOnRydWUsInJlYWRPbmx5IjpmYWxzZSwiY29kZSI6Ii8qKlxuICogWW91IGNhbiBlZGl0LCBydW4sIGFuZCBzaGFyZSB0aGlzIGNvZGUuIFxuICogcGxheS5rb3RsaW5sYW5nLm9yZyBcbiAqL1xuXG5pbXBvcnQgamF2YXguaW1hZ2Vpby4qXG5pbXBvcnQgamF2YS5pby4qXG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhbCBpID0gSW1hZ2VJTy5yZWFkKEZpbGUoXCJcIikpXG59XG4ifQ==

Comment: You are right on the part, that this is something tor shouldn't handle, so I am going to mark your answer as the right one

Comment: @AlexeySoshin - " There's no such thing as "only Kotlin"" -- That is just silly. Of course there is "only Kotlin" classes. Kotlin doesn't _always_ rely on the JVM.

Comment: @Chad Bingham - you're taking it out of context, mate :)

Answer (score 0):

1 - Receive an image file : Like Alexey Soshin pointed out, use whatever suits your needs to read/get the image

2 - Process (resize the image) : using a library such as [thumbnailator](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator)

see example:

[image]